# Snakemake: R script fails (almost) immediately

Tags: r, snakemake, seurat

Once more I'm encountering an error in my snakemake workflow that doesn't make any sense to me.

This is the error I get:

```
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:00 2018] Building DAG of jobs...
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018] Provided cores: 24
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018] Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018] Job counts:
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018]  count   jobs
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018]  1   merging_seurat
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018]  1

[Thu Jan 25 10:47:01 2018] Job 0: --- Merging samples using seurat.

Error in setClass("Snakemake", slots = c(input = "list", output = "list",  : 
  unused argument(s) (slots = c(input = "list", output = "list", params = "list", wildcards = "list", threads = "numeric", log = "list", resources = "list", config = "list", rule = "character"))
Execution halted
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] Error in rule merging_seurat:
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018]     jobid: 0
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018]     output: merging_seurat/12_top10_heatmap_all_wilcox.pdf, merging_seurat/13_top10_heatmap_all_roc.pdf, merging_seurat/merging_seurat.RData

[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] RuleException:
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] CalledProcessError in line 372 of .../snakemake_pipeline/Snakefile:
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] Command ' set -euo pipefail;  Rscript .../snakemake_pipeline/scripts/.snakemake.jv8ijpiw.merging_seurat.R ' returned non-zero exit status 1
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018]   File ".../snakemake_pipeline/Snakefile", line 372, in __rule_merging_seurat
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018]   File ".../tools/anaconda3/envs/Seurat/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
[Thu Jan 25 10:47:02 2018] Complete log: .../snakemake_6/.snakemake/log/2018-01-25T104700.498155.snakemake.log
```

This is the rule in question:

```
rule merging_seurat:
  input:   expand("{sample}/molecule_count/counts_wide.tsv", sample=config["samples"]),
  output:  "merging_seurat/12_top10_heatmap_all_wilcox.pdf",
           "merging_seurat/13_top10_heatmap_all_roc.pdf",
           "merging_seurat/merging_seurat.RData"
  message: "--- Merging samples using seurat."
  script:   "scripts/merging_seurat.R"
```

Here we have the top of the R script that is still executed:

```
sink('merging_seurat/output.txt')
print(installed.packages())
print(sessionInfo())
sink()
```

And these are the following lines in the R script that are not executed anymore:

```
library('Seurat')
library('dplyr')
library('org.Hs.eg.db')
```

Because I logged the packages that are available, I know that the three packages that should be loaded are also installed so it shouldn't fail because of that. In fact, commenting these lines out doesn't change anything, the script still breaks and the log message that should come right after loading the packages is not written to the log file.

Finally, this is the command that I use to run snakemake:

```
snakemake --use-conda \
--latency-wait 90 \
--rerun-incomplete \
--keep-going \
--timestamp \
--cluster-config SGE.json \
--cluster "qsub -cwd -N {cluster.name} -l h_vmem={cluster.h_vmem},h_stack=256M -o {cluster.stdout}{cluster.name}.o -e {cluster.stderr}{cluster.name}.e -m {cluster.mailtype} -M {cluster.mailuser}" \
-j 8 \
--directory .../snakemake_6
```

Does anybody have a clue what the error message could mean? `unused argument` of the snakemake R object is strange because I'm calling multiple parameters later on in the script.

What is even more strange is that I have another R script that works with different packages but has very similar first lines runs fine. I remember that in the beginning I had the same problem with that script (same error message) but don't remember how I solved it.

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Could you change `script:   "scripts/merging_seurat.R"` to `shell: "Rscript scripts/merging_seurat.R"` and  confirm whether you still get the error

Comment: Ok I think I've got some more clues and it all points towards an error when loading the R packages (which would make sense because that's where it crashes, even though when I checked inside the script using installed.packages() the package was there). So, as suggested by you, I ran it with `shell: "Rscript scripts/merging_seurat.R` but that gave me `package 'Seurat' not found`. So I changed it to `.../anaconda3/envs/Seurat/bin/Rscript .../scripts/merging_seurat.R` and now it seems to work. It's all a bit odd but this already helped. Thank you!

Comment: The only problem is that like this snakemake doesn't pass an object with the information from the config file but as a workaround I made a rule that will export this object to an RDS file that I can read from the R script. By the way, the reason that I don't execute the script inside a conda container is that this `Seurat` package isn't available through conda so I can't build a YML file for it :/

Comment: seurat's on CRAN; you can build a release of it and put it on your own repository on anaconda. Or you could try and put it on bioconda

Comment: I tried but it seems that some of its dependencies require the same procedure and at the moment I don't have time to do this. The alternative would be a docker container but also that would have to wait some time.